# Response from the server when saving a record to set the id ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After I save the record using `selection.save()` where selection is my model, id is not being set on the model. My current server response is same as the json for show. i.e: `selection: {id: <id>}` and other fields. Buy id is not set in the ember data local storage.
I'm using the default RESTAdapter and Rails as backend. (I use jbuilder for JSON)

model is `MatchPlayerSelection` and once I save the record, this is the response I send back:

```
{"match_player_selection":{"id":41298,"user":3,"scheduledMatch":133,"matchPlayerScores":[3697,3696,3694,3698,3704,3719,3712,3709,3717,3707,3714],"captain":3694,"viceCaptain":3709}
```

Comment: what REST adapter are you using? what backend are you using? could you show a snippet of your production json? Is it part of a relationship or is this a top level object in the graph?

Comment: It is the top level object. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem. Have you been able to resolve the problem?

Comment: I was unable to resolve and did some workaround then and did not revisit later :(

Answer (score 3):

How are you testing for the `id` getting set?  The `save` function is async and returns a promise, so you need to resolve the promise before checking the `id`.

This will NOT work:

```
selection.save();
console.log( selection.get('id') );
```

This WILL work:

```
selection.save().then(function(savedSelection){
  console.log( savedSelection.get('id') );
});
```